# Show that if $|ε|$ is small enough, then all solutions are bounded of the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to show that if $|ε|$ is small enough, then all solutions are bounded of the ODE:

$$x'' +  [1 + ε \sin 3t]  x = 0$$

I can't figure out how to do this because I can't find a way to solve the equation. Do I need to just show that $x''+x=0$ solutions are bounded so then a small epsilon won't mess up the boundedness?

Comment: Hi, this is an interesting exercise. I'll get back to answer when I've figured it around. By the way, no, it does not work this way. To be correct, you need to prove the case of the solution being bound strictly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Truly, the differential equation :

$$x'' +  [1 + ε \sin (3t)]  x = 0$$

cannot be solved in terms of standard mathematical functions.

Multiplying both sides by $x'$, we get :

$$x''\cdot x' + [1 + ε \sin (3t)]  x\cdot x'=0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}[(x')^2]'+[1+ε\sin(3t)]\cdot \frac{1}{2}(x^2)'=0 $$

Integrating both sides from $0$ to $t$, we'll get :

$$[x'(t)]^2+ \int_0^t [1+ε\sin(3s)]\cdot \frac{1}{2}(x^2)'ds = [x'(0)]^2$$

For small enough $|ε|$, note that $\int_0^t [1+ε\sin(3s)]\cdot \frac{1}{2}(x^2)'ds \geq 0$, so :

$$[x'(t)]^2 \leq     [x'(0)]^2$$

Does this lead us to a conclusion about $x(t)$ ?

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate the help a lot. Seems like it tells us that $y(x)$ is bounded... If the derivative is bounded I think the function would be bounded too.

Comment: How did you get the y into the problem? I am a bit confused on that part. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I am so sorry . It's a misspell, it's $x(t)$, which is the solution of the differential equation (it was so late when I was typing this). Corrected it now !